# How to superpose items in apple Apple Watch UI

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I would like to superpose a button over an image. As long as I have seen over documentation and courses it isn't possible. But there is a hint on apple documentation that make me think it is possible.

[image]

This is what I want:
[image: image overlapped by a tappable button]

Comment: Apple's apps are not bound by the limitations of the WatchKit API.

Comment: Hi jshier, this entire question was about how to do it using WatchKit API to show this effect on an apple watch

Comment: I'm aware. Just have to keep in mind that the effects shown in Apple's apps may not be possible in the public APIs.

Comment: Hi jshier, sorry I didn't understand your previous comment. But, yes, I'm aware of that but that isn't going to stop me :) ...well, maybe it will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to make a group "A". Inside group "A" insert as many buttons as you like inside as many groups you need to get the desired layout.
Assign an image as the background of group "A".
That's all!

Comment: Anyway, seems to be very tricky... is a bit hard to accomplish a good layout easily